# Splittling list of JSON key/value pairs into columns of a row in a Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column with a list of key/value objects:

```
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID  | Settings                                                                                   |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   | [{"key":"key1","value":"val1"}, {"key":"key2","value":"val2"}, {"key":"key3","value":"val3"}] |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to split this list of objects into its own row? 
As such:

```
+----+------+-------+-------+
|ID  | key1 | key2  |  key3 |
+----+------+-------+-------+
|1   | val1 | val2  |  val3 |
+----+------+-------+-------+
```

I've tried exploding, and placing into a Struct:

```
   case class Setting(key: String, value: String)
   val newDF = df.withColumn("setting", explode($"settings"))
                .select($"id", from_json($"setting" Encoders.product[Setting].schema) as 'settings)
```

which gives me:

```
+------+------------------------------+
|ID    |settings                      |
+------+------------------------------+
|1     |[key1,val1]                   |
|1     |[key2,val2]                   |
|1     |[key3,val3]                   |
+------+------------------------------+
```

And from here I can use the specifies rows by such settings.key
But its not quite what I need. I need to access multiple keys in the one row of data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost near, If you already got this

```
+------+------------------------------+
|ID    |settings                      |
+------+------------------------------+
|1     |[key1,val1]                   |
|1     |[key2,val2]                   |
|1     |[key3,val3]                   |
+------+------------------------------+
```

Now you can use pivot to reshape the data as

```
newDF.groupBy($"ID")
  .pivot("settings.key")
  .agg(first("settings.value"))
```

Group by ID and use `pivot`, Use `agg` to get the `first` value but you can use any other `function` here.

Output:

```
+---+----+----+----+
|ID |key1|key2|key3|
+---+----+----+----+
|1  |val1|val2|val3|
+---+----+----+----+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much

Comment: I'm looking for same output, but getting following error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef WrappedArray(key)